# Inducing factor, activating factor, or operating factor?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a term to use in a research paper in order to express the main driving factor behind a sequence of chemical reactions.

Which one is better: Inducing factor, Activating factor, Operating factor

Or is there any other word which may be more appropriate for this condition?

.
.
.And i have to add that this factor that I am talking about is a kind of arrangment not a substance.

Comment: Technical jargon might be better off at its host site. However, as a chem.SE user, this seems to lack enough context for a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, this needs more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could describe more precisely the chemical system to which you are referring. Then those of us with an appropriate scientific background might be in a better position to help. However, I shall provide some advice using biochemical precedents regarding a choice between terms based on the verbs ‘activate’ and ‘induce’, ignoring ‘operate’, which does not appear appropriate.

In plain English the terms have the following meanings:

> **[Activate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/activate)**: Make (something) active or operative.
>
> *‘fumes from cooking are enough to activate the alarm’*
>
> [**Induce**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/induce):
>   Bring about or give rise to.
>
> ‘none of these measures induced a change of policy’
>
> **[Operate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/operate)**: Be in effect.
>
> ‘there is a powerful law which operates in politics’

So I have rejected ‘operate’ because it has the sense of referring to an existing situation, whereas ‘activate’ and ‘induce’ imply a change in a situation.

‘Activate’ and ‘induce’ have subtle differences in implication.

**‘Activate’** may imply that a situation/system is ready to go, lacking only one component or one input to make it operate. This is probably why the term is used in relation to enzymes in biochemistry. The enzyme is already there — may even be operating at a basal level — and the activator interacts with it to enable it to operate at full (or greater) capacity. See, e.g. [Enzyme Activator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_activator) entry in Wikipedia.

**‘Induce’** is less specific in relation to how the situation/system is put into operation. In biochemistry and molecular biology the term ‘inducer’ is often used in relation to gene expression, where the mechanism can be much less direct than the foregoing. For example an inducer might allow the RNA polymerase enzyme to operate on the DNA, not by interacting with it directly (activating it) but by binding to and dislodging a different protein which had been blocking the operation of RNA polymerase along the DNA. See e.g. [Inducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inducer) entry on Wikipedia.

For that reason I suspect ‘inducing factor’ may be the best of your three choices, unless, of course, you feel that it will cause confusion with biological systems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [catalyst](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catalyst) is the term you are looking for.  I am not a chemist, but I know that catalyst has a very specific meaning in chemistry.

> a substance that enables a chemical reaction to proceed at a usually faster rate or under different conditions (as at a lower temperature) than otherwise possible.

This meaning may not apply to your situation.  Catalyst also has a less scientific meaning that might work for you.

> an agent that provokes or speeds significant change or action. *That waterway became the catalyst of the area's industrialization.* *He was the catalyst in the native uprising.*

Consider a reaction that occurs only at high temperature.  "High temperature" could be called a catalyst according to the second definition, but not by the first.

Comment: I don't think this is likely to apply to a *sequence* of chemical reactions. I suspect if it is a sequence it is likely to be in a biological context, where a catalyst would have the name enzyme. There are specific names depending on the mechanism.

Comment: Either enzyme or catalyst is used for substances in chemical and biological contexts. But , the thing that i am talking about is a kind of arrangment, which causes these series of reactions.

Answer (score 0):

How about **causative factor/agency**?

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/causative?s=ts):

> acting as a cause; producing (often followed by of):
>   *a causative agency; an event causative of war.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/causative):

> effective or operating as a cause or agent • *causative* bacteria of cholera